# How to use inspect mode from chrome only for visible elements

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> [inspect mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements#css-styles) from chrome is really cool, but when there is hidden elements on page it highligths them too for selection (which is not a problem) but you cannot select the visible items behind those ones.

I managed to use **delete node** for those items on **elements tab** and then I'm able to select the item of my interest. The problem is that some logic could depend on that hidden items and then I must refresh page to debug or check whatever.

I have searched for a plugin which allow me to select only visible items, but no luck. Is there anything configurable to achieve that functionality?

Comment: They are not _invisible_, they are transparent. Big difference. Their boxes still cover the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `pointer-events:none;` style to the element to allow yourself to click on the elements "behind" the element.

There are several ways of getting an "invisible" box, including but not limited to an element with the `visibility:hidden;` style or an element with a transparent background whose size extends beyond its contained elements. Detecting all of these cases without false positives would be quite a challenge, so the easiest way to get the desired result is to manually set `pointer-events:none;` via the CSS "styles" tab (a panel at the right).

Another useful shortcut within the inspector is <kbd>H</kbd>. By pressing <kbd>H</kbd>, you're toggling the visibility of the element. This allows you to visually hide the element without removing it from the document, e.g. if you want to debug an element that is covered by some other element.

Comment: Mixing this with [stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) should be enough. Pretty cool